# count randomly generated element from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have a problem as such:

```
i = [
    'pic1.gif',
    'pic2.gif'
];
```

I generate a random sequence of n pictures from the two pictures as such:

```
a = function(n){
    str = '<div>'

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        str += '<img src="'+ /*randomElement of array i*/ +'">';
    }

    str += '<div>';

    return str;
}
```

What I need to do now is how to count the number of pic1 generated?

Comment: Just to double confirm, so your question is about `how to count the number of pic1 generated` instead of how to generate `pic.gif` randomly?

Comment: will you have always the same pic name, for which you need the count? eg: you  need to find the cont of "pic1" always? or does the name pic1 keep changing

Comment: after generation, you can just check for pic1 or pic2 and count them by assigning to a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you know the name of the pic, and if does not change, we can find the count using simple variable

```
a = function(n){
str = '<div>'
**//adding a temp variable**
count_img =0;
for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    str += '<img src="'+ /*randomElement of array i*/ +'">';
    **//check the image name
    if(imagename matches){
         //increment the count
         count_img = count_img +1;
    }**
}

**console.log(count_img);**
str += '<div>';

return str;
```

}